# How does type-casting fail but work fine after constructor

Tags: java, list, casting, set

I am exploring Java and while trying type-casting I ran into the following issue, the casting failed when I called the method the first time but after constructing the List it worked fine.

Looking for a clear explanation to this please :)
Thanks

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashMap; // import the HashMap class


public class Main{     
    public static void main(String[] args)     
    {     
        Set<Map<String, ?>> rows = new HashSet();
        
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("1","one");
        map.put("2","two");
        
        HashMap<String, String> mapp = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mapp.put("3","three");
        mapp.put("4","four");
        
        rows.add(map);
        rows.add(mapp);

        //WHY THE FOLLOWING DOESN'T WORK ?????
        //printItems((List<Map<String, ?>>) rows);
        
        //BUT THE FOLLOWING WORKS FINE
        List<Map<String, ?>> listedRows = new ArrayList<>(rows);
        printItems(listedRows);
    }
    
    public static void printItems(List<Map<String, ?>> items) {
        for (Map<String, ?> str: items)
            System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can actually use set or list if the method printItems has argument Collection<Map<String,?>> items instead of List, and since Set doesnot extends List interface, instead both List and Set extends Collection interface.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the run-time type of `rows` is `HashSet` and `HashSet` does not implement the `List` interface.

It works when you create `listedRows` because the run-time type of that object is `ArrayList` which does implement the `List` interface.

In your example, you could just just use the `Collection` abstraction in `printItems` since all you need to do is iterate through items.  This will allow you to invoke the method with a `Set` or `List` (or any other [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)) without having to cast or recreate an object.

```
    public static void printItems(Collection<Map<String, ?>> items) {
        for (Map<String, ?> str: items)
            System.out.println(str);
    }
```

---

On casting if you are interested:

Casting generally only works when you have an object with a compile-time type that is a parent class of the run-time type and you need to coerce the compile-time type of the object to be the run-time type so that you can invoke a method that is specific to the run-time type.

For example (albeit contrived):

```
public void addTenObjects(List l) {

  if (l instanceof ArrayList)
    ((ArrayList)l).ensureCapacity(10)
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    l.add(new Object())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `Set` and `List` interfaces extend `Collection`, but they don't extend each other. I.e. they are sibling, therefore you can't convert one into another via casting.

Since your method `printItems` simply printing the contents of the argument passed into it, you can use instead of it Java 8 [`Iterable.forEach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)), which expects a `Consumer` representing the action:

```
rows.forEach(System.out::println);
```

No need to type-cast or copy anything, and no need in introducing the method when you have a fairly simple logic like in this case.